# Outer products among more than three vectors in Julia

Tags: julia, tensor

I am looking for a way to calculate outer products among more than three vectors in Julia.

Let `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are vectors that each size is `I`, `J`, `K` and `L`, respectively. Then, their outer products of them are defined as a tensor `T` whose size is `I x J x K x L`, and each element is defined as

T[i,j,k,l] = a[i]*b[j]*c[k]*d[l]

Is there any helpful function in Julia to get `T` from vectors?

**EDIT**

I posted a new question about `outer` function without memory allocation.

[Outer products without memory allocation in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77813792/outer-products-without-memory-allocation-in-julia)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for here is `kron`. Taking the Kronecker product of vectors will give vectors, so you can get the desired tensor by reshaping, so in your case
`reshape(kron(d,c,b,a),(I,J,K,L))`
or more generally
`reshape(kron(d,c,b,c),length.((a,b,c,d)))`. I usually define a function to remember the ordering for me

```
outer(v...) = reshape(kron(reverse(v)...),length.(v))
```

So this is how you take the outer product of *vectors*, of course you could ask whether you can do similar for tensors more generally. Here is a little more tedious to deal with the sizes, but yea you can do the same trick

```
outer(v...) = reshape(kron(reverse(vec.(v))...),tuple(vcat(collect.(size.(v))...)...))
```

Comment: Seems like a job for Tullio.jl?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect case for Tullio.jl, `@tullio T[i,j,k,l] := a[i]*b[j]*c[k]*d[l]` will do that.

Comment: @tullio seems to be faster than `outer()`. But the code `@tullio T[i,j,k,l] := a[i]*b[j]*c[k]*d[l] ` is for only 4th order tensors. Can we generalize the tullio code for general dimension?

Comment: I posted the related question in
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/tullio-for-general-dimensional-tensors/104787/2

Answer (score 3):

You can just broadcast `*` after reshaping:

```
julia> a,b,c,d = (rand(1+i) for i in 1:4);

julia> t4 = a .* permutedims(b) .* reshape(c,1,1,:) .* reshape(d,1,1,1,:);

julia> summary(t4)
"2×3×4×5 Array{Float64, 4}"
```

My package translates the notation in the question to precisely this broadcast:

```
julia> using TensorCast

julia> @cast t4c[i,j,k,l] := a[i] * b[j] * c[k] * d[l];

julia> t4c == t4
true
```

This operation is similar to `kron`, but somewhat confusingly the order of its arguments isn't what you'd expect for column-major arrays.

```
julia> kron(b,a) ≈ vec(a .* b') ≈ @cast t2[(i,j)] := a[i] * b[j]
true

julia> kron(d,c,b,a) ≈ @cast _[(i,j,k,l)] := a[i] * b[j] * c[k] * d[l]
true
```