# Outer products without memory allocation in Julia

Tags: arrays, vector, julia, tensor

I am using Julia 1.9.0.

I want a tensor `T` to be overwritten by the outer product of vectors `A1, A2, ... , AD` in each iteration in my program. For example if `D` is 5, I update the tensor `T` as

```
T[i1,i2,i3,i4,i5] .= A1[i1] * A2[i2] * A3[i3] * A4[i4] * A5[i5]
```

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75318197/outer-products-among-more-than-three-vectors-in-julia), I got a function named `outer` which gets `T` from vectors `A1, A2, ..., AD`.

```
outer(v...) = reshape(kron(reverse(v)...),length.(v))
```

However, it requires memory allocation.

```
using BenchmarkTools
T = rand(3,4,8,5);
v = [rand(3), rand(4), rand(8), rand(5)];
@btime $T .= outer($v...)
# 2.582 μs (36 allocations: 6.91 KiB)
```

In my program, I will repeatedly update `T`. So the memory allocation leads to less performance. How can we make such a function `outer!(T, v)` without (or less) memory allocation?

My concern is that, `kron!` does not accept multiple vectors while `kron` accepts. That fact makes it difficult for me to develop the function `outer!(T, v)`.

```
a = rand(4); b = rand(3); ab = rand(4*3);
kron!(ab, a, b); # it works!

a = rand(4); b = rand(3); c = rand(4); ABC = rand(4*3*4)
kron!(ABC, a, b, c);
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching kron!(::Vector{Float64}, ::Vector{Float64}, ::Vector{Float64}, ::Vector{Float64},)
```

--

I guess `@Tulio` might be an alternative approach as follows.

```
@tullio T[i1,i2,i3,i4.i5] := A1[i1]*A2[i2]*A3[i3]*A4[i4]*A5[i5]
```

But I need to implement the program for a general `D`, which I think I should not use @Tulio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this with array operations is:

```
julia> function outer!(dst::AbstractArray, xs::AbstractVector...)
         ys = ntuple(i -> reshape(xs[i], ntuple(_->1, i-1)..., :), length(xs))
         broadcast!(*, dst, ys...)
       end
outer! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a = rand(4); b = rand(3); c = rand(2); abc = rand(4,3,2);

julia> outer!(abc, a, b, c)
4×3×2 Array{Float64, 3}:
...

julia> dan!(similar(abc), a, b, c) == outer!(similar(abc), a, b, c)
true
```

This some allocations from `reshape(::Array, ...)`, but order 1 per `x`, not a copy of the data. It is faster than the `CartesianIndices` loop at large sizes, slower at small.

Answer (score 2):

Tweaking the definition of `ABC` to a tensor of size (4,3,4), makes it possible:

```
julia> a = rand(4); b = rand(3); c = rand(4);

julia> ABC = similar(a, (4,3,4));

julia> for I in CartesianIndices(ABC)
       ABC[I] = prod(getindex.((a,b,c),Tuple(I)))
       end;
```

The `for` loop can be wrapped in a function to mimic `kron` but in the actual code it is pretty readable as is.

ADDED:
Inspired by mcabbott solution which uses broadcast to save on operations. This is a tweak on this version which saves most of the work (especially if first vector in kron is long enough):

```
function dan2!(dst::AbstractArray, x1::AbstractArray, xs::AbstractVector...)
    for I in CartesianIndices(size(dst)[2:end])
        a = 1.0
        for i in 1:length(xs)
            a *= xs[i][I[i]]
        end
        @views dst[:,I] .= a .* x1
    end
end
```

The inner `for` loop should have a better way to be expressed (without allocations).

In some sense, even if the solutions in this answer work faster, mcabbott's solution expressed the intent in a more generic way, which should lead with smarter and smarter compilers to better optimized code.